# How to use the phrase 'For there to be'

Tags: phrase-usage

I've heard that the phrase' For there to be' can be used as infinitive in the Sentences.so, how to use this kind of phrase?

Even if I don't know its usage ,I've tryed to use it in a sentence below:

For there to be a success, we need to struggle.

Am i correct ?
Please provide its usage.

I would appreciate your responses.

Comment: [Here are some written examples](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22for+there+to+be%22&safe=off&tbm=bks).

Answer (score 1):

The pronoun **there** can play the role of a subject of *to*-infinitive clause, just like any other pronoun, *e.g* *me, you etc*

> I expected **there** to be a simpler solution.
>
> We found all the elements for **there** to be a sustained ecosystem.
>
> It's hard for **me** to do.
>
> I want **you** to keep me company.

In all the sentences above, the bolded words are the subject of the *to*-infinitive constructions.

In view of that, your sentence is correct. But in reality such construction of **for there to be** is more common in speech than in written text.